# Javascript Array.map() callback function question about this code from MDN

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods, iterator

I ran in to this code [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Looping_code#map_and_filter) and I'm trying to understand how and why it runs. I could make a number of assumptions but I rather not, I would rather learn what is the actual reason and mechanism that allows this to work. The part that is confusing for me is this `const upperCats = cats.map(toUpper);`

Here is the code:

```js
function toUpper(string) {
    console.log(this);
  return string.toUpperCase();
}

const cats = ["Leopard", "Serval", "Jaguar", "Tiger", "Caracal", "Lion"];

const upperCats = cats.map(toUpper);

console.log(upperCats);
// [ "LEOPARD", "SERVAL", "JAGUAR", "TIGER", "CARACAL", "LION" ]
```

What I was expecting was `const upperCats = cats.map(toUpper(string)`, in short I was expecting a normal function call, but this is not a normal function call, this looks more like an anonymous function call or arrow function call, which again, just makes my head spin.  How and Why?  I mean it is supposed to be calling a normal named function.  But then again `Array.map()` expects a callback function.

I've googled around and stumbled upon the `arguments` object which I used inside the `toUpper()` function to print `console.log(arguments);` to get a better idea of what is going on here, but this didn't help much it only confirmed what I read in this [MDN API Doc for Array map parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#parameters) describes, the callback function is getting 3 parameters - element, index, and array.

Here is sample of the output of console.log(arguments) inside toUpper function.

```js
Arguments { 0: "Leopard", 1: 0, 2: (6) […], … }​
  0: "Leopard"
  1: 0
    2: Array(6) [ "Leopard", "Serval", "Jaguar", "Tiger", "Caracal", "Lion" ]
      0: "Leopard"
      1: "Serval"
      2: "Jaguar"
      3: "Tiger"
      4: "Caracal"
      5: "Lion"
      length: 6
...
Arguments { 0: "Lion", 1: 5, 2: (6) […], … }
```

So again, how and why does that code work?  What kind of JS sorcery make this happen?

Comment: If you would do `cats.map(toUpper(string))`, then you call `toUpper` once. Instead you want the `.map` implementation to call `toUpper` on each value in `cats`. So multiple calls have to be made, and each time with a different argument. The `.map` implementation does this for you, and you only need to provide the function that it should use. In short: you should not *call* the function, but *pass* it.

Comment: I get that the function is being passed, but I want to know how is the parameter passed to the function if is not explicit like in a function call. how does it even know how many parameter to pass?  is there some kind of implicit contract?  What am I missing?

Comment: *"how does it even know how many parameters to pass? Is there some kind of implicit contract?"*: yes there is. That contract is specified in the docs [you referenced](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#parameters): exactly 3 arguments are passed to the callback function. It is your responsibility to have provided a function that deals with these (or not, if you're not interested in some of those).

Comment: Is map using something like an anonymous function to do that, something like  `(element) => callback(element)` is that how that works?

Comment: .map calls the supplied function for each item in the array. The returned value of .map is a new array of the values returned by the supplied function - the MDN docs you linked to explain it quite well, I can't see how anyone could misinterpret them as JS sorcery

Comment: I get it now. Thanks.  Is there a place to see the code for the internal implementation for the Array.map method?  I'm leaning JS, so I don't all the resources yet.

Comment: Well, I find JS to be very quirky, much like Ruby/Rails do automagic, JS has some Quirky Sorcery.   I wish I was more proficient in JS, so I wouldn't have to ask these questions, but I'm not.  Anyway, thank you for taking the time to answer them.

Comment: I just re-read the article and I see where I went wrong.  I misunderstood what it meant by calling the provided callback once for each element and go hung up on the code where .map() is getting called and the callback function is getting passed.  Thanks.  It took I while but I got there. I won't be forgetting that anytime soon.

Comment: is this the way that internal implementation does the calling? `callback.call(this, element);`